# ASP.NET MVC list embedded in model, not returning from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model with a couple of fields and a list of objects. The list of objects is returning `null`. Any help would be appreciated as I can't see what's happening here!

My model classes are:

```cs
public class TradeDiscount 
{
    public int TradeCustomerId {  get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryGroupIdentifier { get; set; }
}

public class TradeCustomerDetails 
{
    public List<TradeDiscount> discounts { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```cs
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    TradeCustomerDetails tradeCustomerDetails = repo.GetCustomerDiscountDetails(id);

    return View(tradeCustomerDetails);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(TradeCustomerDetails tradeCustomerDetails) 
{
    repo.SaveCustomerDiscoutDetails(tradeCustomerDetails);

    return View(tradeCustomerDetails);
}
```

Finally, my view is:

```
@model Trade_Counter.Models.TradeCustomerDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Discount Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Discount Details</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid form-horizontal">
        <h4>Details for @Model.CustomerName </h4>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)

        @foreach (var deets in Model.discounts) {
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => deets.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => deets.TradeCustomerId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => deets.CategoryGroupIdentifier)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => deets.Discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The 2<sup>nd</sup> top level values come back fine, but the list is `null`.

Thanks in advance :-)

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use indexing to make the MVC binding work properly for the list:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.discounts.Count(); ++i)
{
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.discounts[i].CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.discounts[i].TradeCustomerId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.discounts[i].CategoryGroupIdentifier)
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.discounts[i].Discount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: The second I saw this, I had a "You idiot" moment!  Thank you, this is of course the correct solution.